# Insert a Pixmap created in another class

Tags: python, pyqt, qpixmap

I am trying to create a `QMainWindow` and add some `QDockWidget`, `QPushButtons` and an image in it. I created the image in a different class so i can add some characteristics later.

I need to put the buttons and the image in the left side of the `QMainWindow`. Something like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are some `QPushButton` there and the `QDockWidget` with a matplotlib figure in each of them.

The problem comes when i want to add the image. I need it to be located in the lower left corner of the `QMainWindow`.

This is part of the code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.my_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.my_widget)

    self.createDockWindows()
    self.createButtons()

  def createDockWindows(self):
    #Here I create two QDockWidget and
    #I add into them a matplotlib figure created in another class

    self.fig1 = mpl_Canvas()    #This is the matplotlib figure`s class
    self.fig2 = mpl_Canvas()

    dock1.setWidget(self.fig1)
    dock2.setWidget(self.fig2)

    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock1)
    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock2)

def createButtons(self):
    #Here i add some buttons  
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.r_btn = QRadioButton()
    self.r_btn.setGeometry(10, 50, 10, 30)
    self.r_btn.setText("RadioButton 1")

    ###HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE IMAGE FROM THE CREATEIMAGE CLASS###

    self.image = createImage()

    layout.addWidget(self.r_btn)
    layout.addWidget(self.image)

    self.my_widget.setLayout(layout)

class createImage(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)

    self.showImage()

  def showImage(self):
    self.label = QLabel()
    self.img = QPixmap("image.jpg")
    self.img_scaled = self.img.scaled(self.label.size(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    self.label.setPixmap(self.img_scaled)
```

How can i do this? I know that i am doing something wrong but i can`t find the mistake.

Hope you can help me.

### -------- EDIT ---------

This is the code with the modifications from @K.Mulier:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.my_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.my_widget)

    self.createDockWindows()
    self.createButtons()

  def createDockWindows(self):
    dock1 = QDockWidget("Osciloscope",self)
    dock1.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

    dock2 = QDockWidget("Espectrometer", self)
    dock2.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable
        | QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable)

    dock1.setMinimumSize(800,100)
    dock2.setMinimumSize(800,100)

    self.fig1 = mpl_Canvas()
    self.fig2 = mpl_Canvas()

    dock1.setWidget(self.fig1)
    dock2.setWidget(self.fig2)

    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock1)
    self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock2)

  def createButtons(self):
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.r_btn = QRadioButton()
    self.r_btn.setGeometry(10, 50, 10, 30)
    self.r_btn.setText("RadioButton 1")

    self.image = createImage()

    layout.addWidget(self.r_btn)
    layout.addWidget(self.image)

    self.my_widget.setLayout(layout)

class createImage(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(createImage, self).__init__(parent = None)
    self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    self.showImage()


  def showImage(self):

    picPath = os.getcwd() + "C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\hello.png"
    print picPath
    picMap = QPixmap(picPath)

    picLabel = QLabel(parent = None)
    picLabel.setGeometry(10,10,800,600)
    picLabel.setPixmap(picMap.scaled(780,580,Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(picLabel)

class mpl_canvas(self):
  #A matplotlib figure
```

### EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED

The problem in the last code is in these lines:

```
picPath = os.getcwd() + "C:\somedirectory\image.png"
print picPath
picMap = QPixmap(picPath)
```

You must replace `picPath` in `picMap = QPixmap(picPath)` with the location of the image like this:

`picMap = QPixmap(C:\somedirectory\image.png")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyImage(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyImage, self).__init__(parent = None)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setPicture()

    def setPicture(self):
        picPath = os.getcwd() + "/someFolder/image.jpg"
        print(picPath) # Check if the path to your picture is correct.
        picMap = QtGui.QPixmap(picPath)

        picLabel = QtGui.QLabel(parent = None)
        picLabel.setGeometry(10,10,800,600)
        picLabel.setPixmap(picMap.scaled(780,580,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(picLabel)
```

If you've got some more questions, don't hesitate to ask. I'd be happy to help you out.

**EDIT**

I've tested it all out on your code. *Apparently it doesn't work for .jpg files, only for .png files.* So you should convert your picture to a .png file, and then run this code (this is your code, with some minor changes):

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget
from PyQt4.QtGui import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtGui import QRadioButton
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.my_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.my_widget)

        self.createDockWindows()
        self.createButtons()

        self.show()

    def createDockWindows(self):
        #Here I create two QDockWidget and
        #I add into them a matplotlib figure created in another class

        # I do not have your matplotlib figures, so I've inserted
        # some labels instead.
        self.fig1 = QLabel("Hello")    #This is the matplotlib figure`s class
        self.fig2 = QLabel("World")

        dock1 = QDockWidget()
        dock2 = QDockWidget()

        dock1.setWidget(self.fig1)
        dock2.setWidget(self.fig2)

        self.addDockWidget(0x2, dock1)
        self.addDockWidget(0x2, dock2)

    def createButtons(self):
        #Here i add some buttons  
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.r_btn = QRadioButton()
        self.r_btn.setGeometry(10, 50, 10, 30)
        self.r_btn.setText("RadioButton 1")

        ###HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE IMAGE FROM THE CREATEIMAGE CLASS###

        self.image = MyImage()

        layout.addWidget(self.r_btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.image)

        self.my_widget.setLayout(layout)

class MyImage(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyImage, self).__init__(parent = None)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setPicture()

    def setPicture(self):
        # For some reason, it only works on .png files, not on .jpg files!
        picPath = os.getcwd() + "\someFolder\myImage.png"
        print(picPath) # Check if the path to your picture is correct.
        picMap = QtGui.QPixmap(picPath)

        picLabel = QtGui.QLabel(parent = None)
        picLabel.setGeometry(10,10,800,600)
        picLabel.setPixmap(picMap.scaled(780,580,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(picLabel)


if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please run this code, and let me know if it worked for you.

**SECOND EDIT**

Here are a few extra remarks to make it work:

(1) The .png file should be a 'genuine' .png file. Just renaming your .jpg file into a .png file won't work. I've tried it.

(2) Please don't forget that `os.getcwd()` already implies a large part of the path. Therefore it is important to check the output of the print statement: `print(picPath)`. Check if this path is correctly referring to your picture.

**THIRD EDIT**

Even converting your .jpg picture into a .png picture using Paint will not work. If you still get the error, please go to this website to download a genuine .png format picture. And try it over with that one: 
http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/mortarboard_123402

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. I wrote your code and i get this error: `QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap` and it does not shows the picture. Is this because of the .png format?

Comment: Hi Pablo,
Make sure that your picture is a .png file, and that the picPath is correct (including the file name, which should end in .png)

Comment: Yes i did. This is the path: `picPath = os.getcwd() + "C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\hello.png"`

Comment: Hi Pablo,
The .png file should be a 'genuine' .png file. Just renaming your .jpg file into a .png file won't work. I've tried it.

Comment: Oh, and I see another problem. When you say `picPath = os.getcwd() + "C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\hello.png" ` , you actually make a wrong path. Because `os.getcwd()` already implies the start of the path `"C:\Users\.."`

Comment: Yes it is a genuine .png. I created with "paint" to check the code. And i already tried using only: `"Flosh\Desktop\hello.png"` and it is the same. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Hi Pablo, please refresh your browser. I've edited some more in my answer. I hope it helps you.
Kind greetings,
Kristof

Comment: Hi Pablo, I have an idea,
Please surf to this website:
http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/mortarboard_123402
You can download an icon as a .png format picture. Then put it in the right folder, and try to portray that one in your GUI. Then you are at least sure that you have a genuine .png format picture.

Comment: Hi @PabloFlores , did my last edit on my answer help you out? Please let me know if it worked for you. I'd be happy to know if your problem is solved. Kind greetings, Kristof

Comment: Thank you for tour answer @K.Mulier , i edited my question to show the answer to the problem i had. Thank you again for everything.

Comment: Good job Pablo!
I'm happy that your problem is solved now :-)
Kind greetings,